# Auditd: reboot/login logs are not being added

Tags: ubuntu, linux-audit

I've configured auditd to monitor reboots/shutdowns/logins. Tried adding file system rules and syscall rules in a following way:

```
-w /sbin/shutdown -p x -k power
-w /sbin/poweroff -p x -k power
-w /sbin/reboot -p x -k power
-w /sbin/halt -p x -k power
```

and syscall way:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/sbin/reboot -k power    
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/sbin/halt -k power
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/sbin/poweroff -k power
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -F path=/sbin/shutdown -k power
```

None of these seem to get the job done, while other logs get added normally. e.g following one results in producing logs as expected:

```
-w /usr/bin/dpkg -p x -k apps
```

I tried it on different devices and two versions of Ubuntu - 16.04 and 18.04

Comment: could you please share the output for `auditctl -l | grep reboot`

Comment: @binarysta The rule is added properly, that's why it's confusing for me. Here's the output:
`-w /sbin/reboot -p x -k power`
Obviously syscall rule is not implemented at the moment, so it only outputs file system rule.

Comment: output for `ausearch -k power` is empty then?

Comment: It only lists changes in config, nothing else

Comment: From tests I just did, it appears it's caused by the fact that all these commands are **symlinks** to systemctl and the arguments appears to have to be absolute (ie resolved like by using readlink -e). I didn't find a replacement method to be able to filter with something useful. affects exe= and path= parameters. Can't filter a string on a0: the man tells a0 can't be a string (because it would be a pointer then).

Comment: so if you audit on /bin/systemctl, you'll get results (too many results).

Comment: If your system symlinks `sg` to `newgrp`, this could be a less expensive method to test this.